# Display shared preference in textview

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a simple calculator app and want the final calculation result to not disappear once the app closes.

I can get the numbers that are inputted by the user to stay in place and the result is calculated correctly, however once the app closes the result disappears?!

Any help would be much appreciated!!

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculator);

    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    editText3.setText(prefs.getString("autoSave", ""));
    editText4.setText(prefs.getString("autoSave1", ""));
    editText6.setText(prefs.getString("autoSave2", ""));
    editText8.setText(prefs.getString("autoSave3", ""));



    editText3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            textViewResult.setText(addNumbers());
        }


        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            prefs.edit().putString("autoSave", s.toString()).commit();
        }


    });

    editText4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            textViewResult.setText(addNumbers());

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            prefs.edit().putString("autoSave1", s.toString()).commit();
        }
    });

    editText6.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {


        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            textViewResult.setText(addNumbers());

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            prefs.edit().putString("autoSave2", s.toString()).commit();
        }
    });

    editText8.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {


        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            textViewResult.setText(addNumbers());

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            prefs.edit().putString("autoSave3", s.toString()).commit();
        }
    });
}

private String addNumbers() {
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int number3;
    int number4;
    if (editText3.getText().toString() != "" && editText3.getText().length() > 0) {
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(editText3.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number1 = 0;
    }
    if (editText4.getText().toString() != "" && editText4.getText().length() > 0) {
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(editText4.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number2 = 0;
    }
    if (editText6.getText().toString() != "" && editText6.getText().length() > 0) {
        number3 = Integer.parseInt(editText6.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number3 = 0;
    }
    if (editText8.getText().toString() != "" && editText8.getText().length() > 0) {
        number4 = Integer.parseInt(editText8.getText().toString());
    } else {
        number4 = 0;
    }

    int sum = (number1 * 2) + (number2 * 4) + (number3 * 2) + (number4 * 2);
    if (sum > 6) sum = 6;
    return sum + "";

} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

First, save your **`result`** to **`preferences`** in **`addNumbers`** method using

```
prefs.edit().putString("result", sum.toString()).commit();
```

See the Changes to your **`addNumbers`** method below-:

```
private String addNumbers() {
int number1;
int number2;
int number3;
int number4;
if (editText3.getText().toString() != "" && editText3.getText().length() > 0) {
    number1 = Integer.parseInt(editText3.getText().toString());
} else {
    number1 = 0;
}
if (editText4.getText().toString() != "" && editText4.getText().length() > 0) {
    number2 = Integer.parseInt(editText4.getText().toString());
} else {
    number2 = 0;
}
if (editText6.getText().toString() != "" && editText6.getText().length() > 0) {
    number3 = Integer.parseInt(editText6.getText().toString());
} else {
    number3 = 0;
}
if (editText8.getText().toString() != "" && editText8.getText().length() > 0) {
    number4 = Integer.parseInt(editText8.getText().toString());
} else {
    number4 = 0;
}

int sum = (number1 * 2) + (number2 * 4) + (number3 * 2) + (number4 * 2);
if (sum > 6) sum = 6;
prefs.edit().putString("result", sum.toString()).commit();
return sum + "";

  } 
}
```

Where **`result`** is your key. so to get the value which you have stored you can use **`prefs`** with the same key like

```
prefs.getString("result","");
```

Get the value from **`preference`** in **`onCreate`** and set this value to your **`TextView`**. See the sample code below

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculator);

    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    String result= prefs.getString("result",""); //where "" is your default value
    if(!result.equals("") && !result.isEmpty()){
      textViewResult.setText(addNumbers());
    }


/*other code*/
```

Comment: Glad to help you @J.Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You can save your result where you are showing the calculated result to the text view, then you'll get what you save and what you show to the user

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your SharedPreference as follows,

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like bellow..

1. Create a method to save SharedPreferences

   ```
    private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
           .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      Editor edit = sp.edit();
     edit.putString(key, value);
     edit.commit();
    }
   ```
2. Save value to method like

   ```
   savePreferences("autosave", s.toString());
   ```
3. View data form  from SharedPreferences , Create another method like

   ```
   private void loadSavedPreferences() {
     SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
           .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);        
      String autosave = sp.getString("autosave", "");

     editText3.setText(autosave);

   }
   ```
4. Call **loadSavedPreferences** method in **oncreate** mehtod in activity & enjoy it...
   Thanks...